# How do I use Mac's Preview application text speech feature?

Tags: mac, preview

How could I let Preview start speaking a selected paragraph? I found the speech menu item in the edit menu but this starts speaking from the beginning of the document!

Comment: This works for every app on my Mac EXCEPT for Preview... so annoying.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a convenient way of making your Mac speak any selected text.

1. Open **System Preferences**.
2. Select **Speech**.
3. Select the **Text to Speech** tab if it is not already selected.
4. Check the box for **Speak selected text when the key is pressed** and provide a key combination of your choice.

You can now use the key combination to speak selected text system-wide.

Comment: I did the instructions above, pressed the right key combo and nothing was said

Answer (score 1):

I read the above comment and tried to follow the instructions I was unsuccessful (as I didn't highlight the text).  Although, having now solved the issue you need to highlight the selected text and then press the key combination (mine is ctrl+s).

Now I use it on all applications including preview, Microsoft Word, chrome etc.  I love it.